# Erro ao gerar Id automaticamente no hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Estou fazendo uma aplicação com hibernate, mas está gerando e o erro:

"ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save()"

A classe que está dizendo que está errado está assim..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class TodoModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id_todo;
    private String nomeTodo;
    private String usuario;
...Getters/Setters/HashCode/Equals..
```

E a tabela foi criado desta forma

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
id_todo INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nomeTodo VARCHAR(15),
usuario VARCHAR(15),
PRIMARY KEY (id_todo)
);
```

Mesmo trocando o método GenerationType para IDENTITY não funcionou. As soluções que vejo por aí sempre sugerem colocar IDENTITY ou AUTO que iria funcionar, mas aqui não funcionou.

O que pode ser?

Comment: Tente acrescentar as seguintes anotações: `@Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id_todo",unique=true, nullable = false)`

Comment: Já tinha visto essa solução em um outro tópico. Não funcionou também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lendo a documentação vi que estava faltando uma tag no xml que mapeia a classe

Antes tava assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="aprendizagem.model.TodoModel" table="USER">
        <id name="id_todo" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="id_todo" />
        </id>
        <property name="nomeTodo" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="nomeTodo" />
        </property>
        <property name="usuario" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="usuario" />
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

e agora adicionando a tag

```
<generator class="increment" />
```

Código

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="aprendizagem.model.TodoModel" table="USER">
        <id name="id_todo" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="id_todo" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="nomeTodo" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="nomeTodo" />
        </property>
        <property name="usuario" type="java.lang.String">
            <column name="usuario" />
        </property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```